# Local images on GitHub main branch not being loaded into AWS amplify preview

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, github, aws-amplify

Thanks for stopping by. I'm having an issue with AWS amplify preview not showing two images that I have in a local directory. The amplify preview pulls from the main branch on GitHub, and redeploys every time I push to main. Every other image I have shows up on the preview, even another one I have that's in the same directory. For the two images that aren't showing up, I am getting "404 not found" logs in the Google Chrome dev tools console as well is in the AWS logs, yet the images are in the main branch on GitHub. Below are some screenshots that may be helpful. I don't have enough rep to post images yet unfortunately.

[Error message in console. (This one is actually on Firefox tools)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM4Lu.png)

[Proof that the images are on GitHub, in the main branch where they should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxmLY.png)

[The image on the left is in the same directory as the images that should be on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAFJn.png)

If anyone has had this sort of issue with their amplify preview and fixed it, or if anyone knows what could possibly be the cause of this, any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.
Lastly, if any more clarity or information is needed I would be happy to oblige.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed to use relative path to the images. I added a slash to the beginning of the src strings in question, and the images showed up.
I don't know if anyone will ever end up here, but if you have this issue just add a slash at the beginning of your src string like below:

```
<img src="/assets/images/photo.jpg" />
```